# Are garage door locks that cannot be opened from the outside available?

Tags: garage, security, lock

I would like to replace my garage lock with a lock face that does not permit opening it from the outside.  I don't have a key to it anyway, and right now it's the weakest link of my home security.

I've not been able to find a solution for this, however.  Can you recommend any replacement lock faces that are simply plates, without a key hole?

Comment: You could squirt the key hole slot full of epoxy. A grey steel filled type like JB-Weld may be suitable.

Comment: What about installing a simple deadbolt?

Answer (score 4):

if you really only need to be able to operate this from inside the garage door, a simple sliding lock may fit the bill.

[image: lock]
<sub>(source: [prodoorparts.com](http://www.prodoorparts.com/uploads/products/medium/Pro%20Door%20Parts%2010%20001.JPG))</sub>

they install on the door and the bar slides into a hole on the garage door track.

Comment: Works great for ventilation as well. Mount one so the door goes up far enough to create a 4" slot. The upper panel moves in enough to exhaust the hot air, lower pulls in cool. But as a non-reachable lock device, this is inexpensive and effective as long as there's no window within reach to break out. And the hole on the end will take a padlock large enough to not pull through the track slot or 5" bolt with nut through and will prevent even that. And will work better than jury-rigging the standard garage door lock mechanism that sometimes can be really easy to defeat.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I know of is to drill a hole in the track large enough to insert a padlock through.  With the garage door closed, you want the hole to be close to a roller so there is limited travel of the door.